# How do I construct a bijection to prove the $q$-binomial theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs, q-analogs

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} q^{\binom{k}{2}} \binom{n}{k}_q x^k = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(1+xq^i\right),\quad \forall \ n\ge 1
\end{align*}

This problem can be solved by mathematical induction, but I want to find a combinatorial proof.

Comment: What is your combinatorial definition of $\binom{n}{k}_q$? Do you count the $k$-dimensional subspaces of $(\mathbb{F}_q)^n$?

Comment: You can do it by counting partitions. The RHS is the generating function for partitions fitting into an $n \times n$ box all of whose parts are distinct, where the coefficient of $x$ counts the number of parts and the coefficient of $q$ counts the sum of the parts. So you need to show that the LHS collects like terms in $x$.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan. I'm confused about how the coefficient of  counts the number of parts while the coefficient of  counts the sum of the parts. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof without induction (but no combinatorial proof, hence I will make this answer CW):

Let
$$f(x) := \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (1+q^i x) = (1+x)(1+qx) \cdots (1+q^{n-1} x).$$
Then one can easily check
$$(1+x)\, f(qx) = (1+q^n x) \,f(x).$$
So, if $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} f_k x^k$ with coefficients $f_k \in \mathbb{Z}[q]$, then
$$f_k \, q^k + f_{k-1} \, q^{k-1} = f_k + q^n\, f_{k-1}.$$
Equivalently,
$$f_k = f_{k-1} \frac{q^n - q^{k-1}}{q^k - 1} = f_{k-1} \frac{q^{n-k+1} - 1}{q^k-1} q^{k-1}.$$
Also, $f_0 = 1$. Hence,
$$f_k = \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{q^{n-i+1}-1}{q^i-1} ~ q^{\large \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} i} = \binom{n}{k}_q \,q^{k(k-1)/2}$$